# IOError when uploading the data

Tags: graphlab, sframe

Is there any data size limits in the graphlab?
I have an IOError when I try to link up the file.

```
products = graphlab.SFrame('C:\Machine Learning\Week3\amazon_baby.gl/')
```

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

As in picture, I can see that the file amazon_baby.gl is not found. I would suggest to rename your folder `Machine Learning` to one word `MachineLearning` and try again. In many cases, extra space creates problems.

You can also right click on the `amazon_baby.gl` folder and copy `path` and then paste

```
products = graphlab.SFrame(' _____Path______')
```